# Help in demonstrating the equivalence between two trigonometric formulas

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I need help demonstrating the equivalence of those two formulas.
For positive values of $A$, they are equivalent and I need to understand how to convert from one equation to another.

$\theta=\arccos{\left(1-\dfrac{A^2}{4R^2}\right)}$

$\theta=2\arcsin{\left(\dfrac{A}{2R}\right)}$

$R$ is one side of the two equal sides of an isosceles triangle and $A$ is the base of the triangle.  $\theta$ is the angle opposite to the base

[image]

Comment: $\theta=\alpha$ ?

Comment: Just use $\sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The first formula is wrong. Just applying cosine law (generalized Pythagoras):
$$A^2=R^2+R^2-2R^2\cos\theta\\\cos\theta=\frac{2R^2-A^2}{2R^2}=1-\frac{A^2}{2R^2}$$